# Is it ok to subscribe an Angular Inbuilt observable inside a setInterval() function?

Tags: angular

I am writing a small application where I need to maintain some token system in order to validate the current logged in user. So, I took help of setInterval() in which I wrote a method which fetches updated token from some server. To fetch updated token I am using Angular Inbuilt HttpClient observable. But my question is "Is it okay to subscribe an HTTP client observable inside the setInterval method"

```
setInterval(() => {
      if (this.isLoggedIn) {
        this.someService.getUpdatedToken().subscribe();
      }
    }, 300000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not use the `setInterval`. You should use rxjs `interval` operator as outer observable and compose it with your `this.someService.getUpdatedToken()` observable by using `switchMap` or `mergeMap` like this:

[I am assuming you are using rxjs ver > 5.5].

```
interval(3000000)
.pipe(
   switchMap(() => {
      if(this.isLoggedIn) {
         return this.someService.getUpdatedToken();
      } else {
         //HERE YOU CAN RETURN SOMETHING AS PER YOUR LOGIC
         //ENSURE TO WRAP THE SAME IN OBSERVABLE
         //FOR DEMO PURPOSE I AM RETURNING null WRAPPED IN OBSERVABLE USING of
         return of(null);
      }
   })
).subscribe((token) => {
   //do whatever you want to do with token
   console.log(token);   
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @user2216584. I am going to use the same approach. I am new to Angular and RXJS world. So, sometimes I always feel confused with the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Is ok if you unsubscribe to the observable each time

However a better approach i think would be to emit a value from the observable given X time, so you subscribe once and you work with one subscription

You can use interval observable for that

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html